# Using Parse Platform with JSQMessagesViewController Swift

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I'm a beginner in iOS development and I want to create a chat app using `Parse` and `JSQMessagesViewController`. But when I compiled my project I have 50 errors.

I used CocoaPods to install `JSQMessagesViewController`.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"_ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter", referenced from:
  -[PF_Twitter getLocalTwitterAccountAsync] in Parse(PF_Twitter.o)
"_FBTokenInformationExpirationDateKey", referenced from:
  -[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy cacheTokenInformation:] in ParseFacebookUtils(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
  -[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy expirationDate] in ParseFacebookUtils(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
  -[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy setExpirationDate:] in ParseFacebookUtils(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
```

Answer (score 1):

The missing frameworks needed to be added. In XCode, go to `Project Targets -> General`. Under `Linked Frameworks and Libraries`, add `Social.framework` and `Accounts.framework`.

I had this same issue and adding these 2 frameworks (along with `Bolts`) solved the issue.